# Row wise extraction of common elements from 2 lists of list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of list with equal len in Python (let's say 3 for this example).

```
A = [['Horse','Duck','Goat'],['Rome','New York'],['Apple','Rome','Goat','Boat']]

B = [['Carrot','Duck'],['Car','Boat','Plane'],['Goat','Apple','Boat']]
```

I would like to match elements in each row and create a new list of the common elements. The resultant output I require is:

```
c = [['Duck'],[],['Apple','Goat','Boat']]
```

and,

```
d = [1,0,3] ; where d is a list with the count of common elements at each row.
```

Note that within each row of the list of lists, elements can appear in any order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> A = [['Horse','Duck','Goat'],['Rome','New York'],
         ['Apple','Rome','Goat','Boat']]
>>> B = [['Carrot','Duck'],['Car','Boat','Plane'],
         ['Goat','Apple','Boat']]
>>> c = [[x for x in a if x in b] for a, b in zip(A, map(set, B))]
>>> d = [len(x) for x in c]
>>> # or d = list(map(len, c))    # you can omit `list` in python 2.x
>>> c
[['Duck'], [], ['Apple', 'Goat', 'Boat']]
>>> d
[1, 0, 3]
```

Comment: is the `map(set, B)` due to the `if x in b` lookup?

Comment: Then +1 for scalability

Answer (score 2):

An alternative list comprehension:

```
c = [[x for x in y if x in B[i]] for i, y in enumerate(A)]
# [['Duck'], [], ['Apple', 'Goat', 'Boat']]

d = [len(x) for x in c]
# [1, 0, 3]
```

Alternatively, you could also use this:

```
res = [set(x) & set(y) for x, y in zip(A, B)]
# or  [set(x).intersection(y) for x, y in zip(A, B)] as @Chris_Rands suggested
# [{'Duck'}, set(), {'Apple', 'Goat', 'Boat'}]
```

notice that the format on that last one is not the one you specified but it uses set intersections which are built for these type of operations.

Comment: I like the use of sets, +1, but perhaps `[set(x).intersection(y) for x, y in zip(A, B)]` is more neat

Comment: @Chris_Rands More *neat* as in?.. xD

Comment: Well it saves the 2nd explicit `set` call and the docs talk about the non-operator form as "more readable" but you way is fine too https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection

Comment: @Chris_Rands I always thought that the `intersection()` simply hides the conversion to set but not that it is not performed. I'll look it up

Comment: I agree, that's why I said "explicit"